# Cartesian product in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an excel in this format.

```
+----------+-------+---------+--------+--------+
| TicketId | PubId | PubName | Model1 | Model2 |
+----------+-------+---------+--------+--------+
|     1234 |    12 | abc     | xyz1   | pqr1   |
|     1235 |    34 | iuy     | fgy6   | piu8   |
+----------+-------+---------+--------+--------+
```

and I am targeting to create a table like the one given below.

```
+----------+---------+-------+
| TicketId | Display | Value |
+----------+---------+-------+
|     1234 | PubId   | 12    |
|     1234 | PubName | abc   |
|     1234 | Model1  | xyz1  |
|     1234 | Model2  | pqr1  |
|     1235 | PubId   | 34    |
|     1235 | PubName | iuy   |
|     1235 | Model1  | fgy61 |
|     1235 | Model2  | piu8  |
+----------+---------+-------+
```

I know it is a cartesian product or cross apply (in terms of SQL) but I want to do it in the excel.

Is there a way to do this type of data representation through excel ?

Comment: you would probably need to user power query to 'UnPivot' the data, it would work very similar to how you could UnPivot in SQL

Answer (score 2):

Assume the source data occupies A1:E3.

Assume the destination header occupies G1:I1.

Enter the formulas:

```
G2=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2+(ROW()-2)/4,1))
H2=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,2+MOD((ROW()-2),4)))
I2=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2+(ROW()-2)/4,2+MOD((ROW()-2),4)))
```

Drag G2:I2 down till G9:I9.

Comment: NICE +1, hadn't noticed before how it simply a repeating pattern of fours